# Где держать экземпляры класса?

Tags: c#, классы, объекты, рефакторинг

Есть программа, по обработке некоторых данных, и есть к этой программе приложенные данные (типо прайс-лист). Этот прайс-лист является набором экземпляров класса, и их много, поэтому не хочется объявлять эти экземпляры в блоке Main основной программы, чтобы не засорять его. Где можно ещё держать все эти кземляры, и при необходимости ссылаться к ним

Comment: Можете завести какой-то класс и держать их там, а в `Main` пользоваться этим классом )

Answer (score 1):

*Держите руки в рукавицах, а ягоды в ягодицах.*

Эти экземпляры можно содержать в массиве или в списке. Сама эта переменная может спокойно находится в том же классе, где и метод Main. Поскольку это основной набор данных, с которым работает приложение, то там ему и самое место.

Answer (score 0):

Самый простой способ - создать класс со статическим свойством или переменной List, например:

```
public static class MyData
{
   public static List<YourClass> PriceList { get; set; } 
}
```

Теперь вы можете обращаться к этому списку без объявления класса:

1)Инициализация:

```
MyData.PriceList = new List<YourClass>(); // здесь на ваш выбор как заполнять список, вариаций несколько
```

2)Использование:

```
var data = MyData.PriceList;
```

P.S: Класс не обязательно должен быть статическим